# How to make Polymer core-scroll-header-panel condense with javascript

Tags: javascript, polymer

I want to make a core-scroll-header-panel, scroll when it's clicked.

```
<core-scroll-header-panel
    on-tap="{{panelTap}}"
    id="actionPanel"
    shadow="true"
    condenses="true"
    keepCondensedHeader
    mode="waterfall-tall"
    class="">
    <core-toolbar class="themed narrow" >
    </core-toolbar>
</core-scroll-header-panel>
...
```

the parent element's script section is.

```
panelTap : function() {  /* make it condense here */  }
```

How do I trigger the condense-ing transition?

Comment: I think the easiest way to do this would be to scroll the page itself by writing a scrollTop animation or using jQuery.animate. I don't think that there's a built in method to just condense, instead the element listens for scroll events and adjusts its size every time an event fires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polymer 1.0 has brought us new element5s... the core-header and core-scroll header have moved to paper elements...
So you would want to port your elements to the new version

Also this paper-scroll-header-panel supports an event named paper-header-transform which is triggered when the header is transformed on scroll(as is evident from it's name)

Hope this helps :)

```
<paper-scroll-header-panel
    paper-header-transform="{{panelTap}}"
    id="actionPanel"
    shadow="true"
    condenses="true"
    keepCondensedHeader
    mode="waterfall-tall"
    class="">
    <core-toolbar class="themed narrow" >
    </core-toolbar>
</paper-scroll-header-panel>
```